# Emails being marked as spam

Tags: dns, hosting, mail-server, spf, dkim

I setup my website for one of my subdomains e.g. `app.mydomain.com`
From my website, I'm trying to send emails using `info@mydomain.com`.

I don't have much experience in setting DNS records. I'm trying for weeks but my emails are going inside the spam. I talked to mydomain.com hosting providers and they set DKIM records and suggested to add SPF records as well:
`mydomain txt "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX +ip4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX include:relay.mailchannels.net ~all"`

Even after adding this record, my emails are going inside the spam folder with softfail. I don't know what I'm missing.
One thing, my app.mydomain.com and mydomain.com are hosted on separate servers that's why I've included ip4 for both websites.

I've read that we need to add different SPF records for different domains/subdomains but not sure if I need to add a separate SPF for my subdomain when I'm using mydomain's email address for sending emails. I feel like I'm stuck in a loop.

Can someone please assist me or guide me what should I look into to get to the right track?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the SPF record you included, it seems to be the incorrect format to include "subdomain" after the `ip4`. This should be only an ip address, not a domain.

You may want to do some testing / validation with the tools found on this site - https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx

Comment: sorry for making it confusing, I've added ip4 in your mentioned format but to make things clear I added domain and subdomain in question. I've updated the question, please check now.

Answer (score 0):

ipv4 expects an IP(ipv4). So you should change your SPF to something like this:

```
"v=spf1 a mx ip4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ip4:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXXX include:relay.mailchannels.net ~all"
```

To test, use https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=YOURDOMAIN&run=toolpage.

A good DKIM configuration will help you too.

;)

Comment: sorry for making it confusing, I've added ip4 in your mentioned format but to make things clear I added domain and subdomain in question. I've updated the question, please check now.

Comment: SPF can't accept subdomains, each subdomain needs to have its own SPF. But adding the domain A IPv4, all subdomains in the same server will be granted as a sender.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue is my subdomain is on a different server but the email address I'm using is the actual domain.
e.g. `app.mydomain.com` and email is `info.mydomain.com`
Should I add a separate SPF for app.mydomain.com?

Comment: Yes ! Each domain should have you own SPF record !